# Compare dates in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have that query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   EventLog AS el
               RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Min(id) AS gId
                           FROM   EventLog
                           WHERE  Value IS NOT NULL
                           GROUP  BY Value) AS e
                       ON el.Id = e.gId) AS el
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid           AS uId,
                         Max([timestamp]) AS ts
                  FROM   UserAdditionStamp
                  GROUP  BY UserId) AS ua
              ON el.UserId = ua.uId
WHERE  el.EventTypeId = 3
```

And example data selected from that is:

```
Id  UserId     ts                              TimeStamp
-----------------------------------------------
461  1         2014-11-17 10:01:27.443      2013-01-08 16:28:52.557
468  25        NULL                         2013-01-08 17:06:15.967
441  1         2014-11-17 10:01:27.443      2013-01-09 11:00:43.947
461  29        2013-01-05 16:28:52.557      2013-01-09 13:29:19.143
```

How can I compare `ts` and `TimeStamp` dates? How to get which one is max date?

Main idea is that if `ts` is less than `TimeStamp` I should insert data in another table.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @FelixPamittan I've edited

Comment: You select doesn't match the output columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN coalesce(timestamp,'01/01/1901')>coalesce(ts,'01/01/1901') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END TimeStampBigger
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   EventLog AS el
               RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Min(id) AS gId
                           FROM   EventLog
                           WHERE  Value IS NOT NULL
                           GROUP  BY Value) AS e
                       ON el.Id = e.gId) AS el
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid           AS uId,
                         Max([timestamp]) AS ts
                  FROM   UserAdditionStamp
                  GROUP  BY UserId) AS ua
              ON el.UserId = ua.uId
WHERE  el.EventTypeId = 3
```

`TimeStamp` and `ts` are both available as column names in the outer `select` and can therefore be compared. Either as output in an extra column (as I did it above: `TimeStampBigger`) or as another condition in the `where` clause.